# Get cookie from CookieJar by name

Tags: python, cookies, cookiejar, cookielib

I know that I can iterate through the cookies in a cookiejar, and this would allow me to find a cookie with a particular name - but does the CookieJar object itself have any methods I can call to get a certain cookie by name?

It just saves me having to write a helper method that already exists.

Comment: Not that I can see, no. You could make a function or subclass the CookieJar object, but I'm not sure why no method exists.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, the `__iter__` method will go through each cookie in `CookieJar`.

```
for cookie in cj:
   print cookie.name, cookie.value, cookie.domain #etc etc
```

A cookie is not just a name and value pair.  In its long list (17) of properties, there is `domain` and `path`.  A domain value of `.ibm.com` would be applicable to the website `mail.ibm.com` for example.  A domain value of `ibm.com` and path value of `/abc` would not apply to the web page `ibm.com/index.htm`. So by supplying the name alone is insufficient to find the value of an applicable cookie in `CookieJar`.

Though the `__iter__` method will return a list of `cookie` objects easily, example `list(cj)`, the internal structure of `CookieJar` is not a simple list.  Internals about the `CookieJar` class is [here](http://all-things-pure.blogspot.com/2014/12/that-convoluted-cookielibcookiejar.html).

Answer (score 32):

You can also use [dict_from_cookiejar](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar), which returns a key/value dictionary from a CookieJar. Something like:

```
my_cookies = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(s.cookies)
```

and then access your cookie value by key.

Answer (score 8):

It's undocumented internals, but you can access cookies directly like this: `cookiejar._cookies[domain][path][name]`

Answer (score 1):

cookielib.CookieJar?

you can convert jar to a list and process that, e.g. `{i.name: i for i in list(j)}`

and btw, j._cookies is actually a dict-dict already, though not completely trivially indexed.

cookie jar file?

I thought those were plain text files...