# python requests get cookies

Tags: python, python-requests

```
x = requests.post(url, data=data)
print x.cookies
```

I used the requests library to get some cookies from a website, but I can only get the cookies
from the Response, how to get the cookies from the Request? Thanks!

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use [`requests.Session`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced.html#session-objects) and observe `cookies` before and after a request:

```
>>> import requests
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> print(session.cookies.get_dict())
{}
>>> response = session.get('http://google.com')
>>> print(session.cookies.get_dict())
{'PREF': 'ID=5514c728c9215a9a:FF=0:TM=1406958091:LM=1406958091:S=KfAG0U9jYhrB0XNf', 'NID': '67=TVMYiq2wLMNvJi5SiaONeIQVNqxSc2RAwVrCnuYgTQYAHIZAGESHHPL0xsyM9EMpluLDQgaj3db_V37NjvshV-eoQdA8u43M8UwHMqZdL-S2gjho8j0-Fe1XuH5wYr9v'}
```

Comment: This will not return the `path` and `domain`, any suggestions?

Comment: @OrDuan as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36387083/426790) you can do `r = requests.get('...')` and then iterate over the Cookie objects using `r.cookies._cookies` which is a dictionary whose keys are `[<domain>][<path>]`

Comment: @GregSadetsky oh wow that was years ago, I'm posting the solution I used years ago as an answer :)

Comment: @GregSadetsky I am getting a weird behavior, since mine `r.cookies._cookies` is returning an empty dictionary, while when I access with Firefox or Chrome, I can find them easily with developer tools. Any hint on that?

Comment: @RicardoBarrosLourenço just tried it with requests 2.20.1 and both iterating over `r.cookies` (and getting the `domain` attribute) or accessing `r.cookies._cookies` worked. Could you try it with `http://google.com` ? Could the URL you're accessing be returning something different because of the different user-agent? If you set requests' user-agent to Firefox's, does it work?

Comment: @GregSadetsky when using `google.com` it works. I assume that some routine in Javascript is responsible for rendering such cookies.

Comment: @RicardoBarrosLourenço great point, cookies set by the JavaScript code could be (/ are most probably) the culprit..!

Comment: It's 2021, you can do `r = requests.get(https://...)` then `r.cookies.get_dict()`

Answer (score 21):

If you need the `path` and the`domain` for each cookie, which `get_dict()` is not exposes, you can parse the cookies manually, for instance:

```
[
    {'name': c.name, 'value': c.value, 'domain': c.domain, 'path': c.path}
    for c in session.cookies
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
url = "http://localhost:8070/web/session/authenticate"
data = {}
header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
x = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=header)
print(x.cookies.get_dict())
```