# Python requests. Emulating cookies

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, python-requests

Im trying to scrape the web, but as a output getting an error with `AADSTS165000: Invalid Request`.

My Python code is pretty simple:

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
link = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../login'
email = {'loginfmt':'...',
             'passwd':'...',}
loging = s.post(link, data = email)

f = open('123.txt', 'w')
f.write(loging.text)
f.close()
```

But getting html output wiht `The request did not return all of the form fields. Failure Reasons:[Missing session context cookie;Token was not provided;]`

How can I emulate  all the requirements to sucessefully loggin in and get the html?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091976/python-requests-get-cookies) may answer your question. It address how to get session cookies using `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

To inject cookies into your request, you need to have the cookies ready,

assuming you have that already,

```
cookies = {"key":"value"}
loging = s.post(link, data = email, cookies=cookies)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to grab the session cookies after logging in, and send it with your next request.

So do

```py
cookies = s.cookies.get_dict()
loging = s.post(link, data = email, cookies=cookies)
```