# How to login to site and get a cookies by python

Tags: python, python-requests

How can I login to this [site](https://shahid.mbc.net/en/widgets/login) and get cookies after login by Python? I tried to use `requests` but failed.

```py
import requests
url = 'https://shahid.mbc.net/en/widgets/login'
Login = {'email': 'mail@mail.com',
      'password': 'pass'}
response = requests.get(url,data=Login)
print (response.headers)
print (response.cookies)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use requests.Session.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091976/python-requests-get-cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your email, password and apikey to login in successfully. You will find apikey in network tab. For that you can follow Google Chrome's Dev Tool Network Tab > XHR.

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as req:
    headers = {
        'authority': 'login.mbc.net',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'origin': 'https://shahid.mbc.net',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'referer': 'https://shahid.mbc.net/',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.1199633606.1614921781; WZRK_G=38c72e930fdb4b74837aa643dc47b107; _ga=GA1.1.1880367528.1614921781; _scid=a233719a-6581-477a-a7db-7111775ad5d2; gmid=gmid.ver4.AcbHoSuw-Q.WFFC0rz1YY3Z8Jkf3PSY2-d85Q20q4ngU541yDeCdCPz9Jb4_6zdRw9_rHKK7NHL.4vpNb7p4gJcxVMMRVoaPaKM774BnYDXqsNqgEqF8-DNz6t5OzbeAT9DpKFeAh6cnMbi_rbYE-mVIQT7isOAPIg.sc3; ucid=ctWpLfyUS5YIrftLu6u8-w; hasGmid=ver4; gig_bootstrap_3_Pm0x4fe9XSy6gv04PewESwqZ_HLgUCbXwWWPHCbGmUGFbW1xyHa42dFt0XTVay0T=login_ver4; _fbp=fb.1.1614921782478.439841241; _sctr=1|1614880800000; PAPVisitorId=JL2A8d7cVVZ64SlP4IkRS6AFl9t5nmdv; _ga_9ZLGVMG0QJ=GS1.1.1614921780.1.1.1614924710.2; WZRK_S_65W-567-675Z=%7B%22p%22%3A12%2C%22s%22%3A1614921781%2C%22t%22%3A1614924710%7D',
    }

    data = {
      'loginID': 'Your email', # registered Email
      'password': 'your password',
      'sessionExpiration': '0',
      'targetEnv': 'jssdk',
      'include': 'profile,data',
      'includeUserInfo': 'true',
      'lang': 'en',
      'APIKey': '3_Pm0x4fe9XSy6gv04PewESwqZ_HLgUCbXwWWPHCbGmUGFbW1xyHa42dFt0XTVay0T', # Your apikey
      'sdk': 'js_latest',
      'authMode': 'cookie',
      'pageURL': 'https://login.mbc.net/accounts.login',
      'sdkBuild': '11903',
      'format': 'json'
    }
    req.headers.update(headers)
    r = req.post('https://login.mbc.net/accounts.login',data=data)
    print(r.json()['statusCode']) # 200
    print(r.json()['isRegistered']) # True
    print(r.json()['profile']) # {'email': 'XXX@yyyy.com'}
```

for the successful login output will be:

```
statusCode= 200
isRegistered= True
profile= {'email': 'XXX@yyyy.com'}
```

Comment: thanks islam , its working with me ... Greetings :))