# How do I reach cookie information in python requests?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to write a small script that will allow me to see information related to the cookies set by my website.

I want to know if it has `secure` or `httpOnly` flags set on them. But so far I wasn't able to do it, I only figured out how to get cookie names and values. Here is my current code:

```
r = requests.post('url', data=data, headers=headers)

for (name, cookie) in r.cookies.items():
    print name, cookie
```

So far this works fine, but I want to get information *related* to the cookies, not the value itself. Cookie meta-data if you will.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can extract the information from each cookie individually:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('http://www.about.com')

for cookie in r.cookies:
    print(cookie.__dict__)
    print(cookie.secure)
```

This is because `r.cookies` is an instance of `RequestsCookieJar` which extends from `CookieJar` (Python 2: `cookielib.CookieJar`, Python 3: `http.cookiejar.CookieJar`). A `CookieJar` has `Cookie` objects.

**References:**

- cookielib: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/cookielib.html
- cookielib.Cookie.secure: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.Cookie.secure
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27523891/295246

**Update:**
I have not found a way to retrieve the `httponly` value from a `Cookie` object. In Python 3, you can define a `Morsel` object via a dictionary, and it considers `httponly` to be a standard attribute of a cookie (https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html), but I couldn't find any reference to `httponly` in the defining specification RFC2109 (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt).

That said, if `httponly` is in fact a non-standard attribute, then you can use the following to check if a cookie has it:
`cookie.has_nonstandard_attr('httponly')`

Comment: You can simply `for cookie in r.cookies:` and you also don't need to import the print_function

Comment: Ah nice :) but I saw that it doesn't work for `httpOnly`. At least not on 2.7. Is there a way to reach that one?

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki, I'm not entirely sure about this, but it seems `httponly` is not part of the standard attributes expected in a cookie according to RFC2109 (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt). You can check if a cookie contains non standard attributes though like so `cookie.has_nonstandard_attr('httponly')`. Though there's contradicting evidence that `httponly` may also be valid (see: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/http.cookies.html#http.cookies.Morsel). Just can't find a single reference to it in the RFC2109 document.

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE, I see.. I was just curious really, but I can take care of it from now on :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Under Python 3, I was not able to retrieve the `httpOnly` flag from the following:

```
cookie.get_nonstandard_attr('httpOnly')
```

and

```
cookie.has_nonstandard_attr('httpOnly')
```

returned `False` even if the `httpOnly` flag was included with the cookie.

This didn't work with any of the variations of `httponly`, `HttpOnly`, etc. either.

Using @HEADLESS_0NE's post, I found you can retrieve the flag by looking at the `_rest` field in `cookie.__dict__`. If `httpOnly` is included in the cookie,

```
cookie.__dict__['_rest']
```

will return something like this:

```
{'HttpOnly': None, ...}
```

Thus, here is a small helper function to check if a cookie has the `httpOnly` flag.

```
def has_http_only(cookie):
    extra_args = cookie.__dict__.get('_rest')
    if extra_args:
        for key in extra_args.keys():
            if key.lower() == 'httponly':
                return True

    return False
```

The secure flag is automatically added to the `cookie` object and can be retrieved using `cookie.secure`.

Comment: The `cookie.has_nonstandard_attr` may not have worked originally because it looks like there were some changes to the casing that Python uses for `HttpOnly`. Mixed case is currently correct and was updated a couple of versions ago. https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/0d8380c493ad